# Why am I getting this result? Simple loop to reverse a string

Tags: java, string

I'm confused.  The logic is sound, yet I get this strange mirrored-down-the-middle string at the end.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String x = "Hello";
    char str[] = x.toCharArray();
    char done[] = str;
    int doneMarker = 0;
    System.out.println("str.length is: " + str.length);
    for (int i= str.length-1; i>(-1); i--)
    {
        done[doneMarker] = str[i];
        doneMarker++;
        System.out.println("i = " + i);
        System.out.println("doneMarker = " + doneMarker);
    }

    String reversed = new String(done);
    System.out.println(reversed);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps the logic is not sound.

Answer (score 4):

When you do:

`char done[] = str;`

you're pointing `done` to `str` and thus you start changing your original char array.

Side note:

`for (int i= str.length-1; i>(-1); i--)`

is usually written as

`for (int i=str.length-1; i>=0; i--)`

Also, you don't need a second counter.
You can simplify the whole thing a lot.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String x = "Hello";
    char str[] = x.toCharArray();
    char done[] = new char[str.length];
    System.out.println("str.length is: " + str.length);
    for (int i=str.length-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        done[i] = str[str.length - 1 - i];
        System.out.println("i = " + i);
    }
    String reversed = new String(done);
    System.out.println(reversed);
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see.  I figured that when I initialized done[] to str[], it was just a one-time thing, and made a copy.  But now I get it.  Both are referring to the same spot in memory, so as one is changed, so is the other.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
char done[] = str;
```

This causes `done` to reference the same data that `str` does, and is effectively the same as replacing `done` with `str` in your code. Modifying the data through `done` modifies `str` as well, then.

You can either create a copy of the data ([`Arrays.copyOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28char%5B%5D,%20int%29)), e.g.

```
char done[] = Arrays.copyOf(str, str.length);
```

Or, the more traditional algorithm (if in-place modification is OK) is to loop through one half of the input string and swap characters with the corresponding position in the second half.

Alternatively, if you store the data in a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) (e.g. [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)) you can use the one-liner [`Collections.reverse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse%28java.util.List%29).